# How to redirect to another page after successful Google Sign In in React18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having an issue when trying to redirect to a different page after signing in with Google with my React 18 project. After logging in with google no redirects happen and I have no clue why not. Here is my Login.jsx file.
After clicking the Google Login button on my react page and successfully logging in with Google nothing changes.

```
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login';
import { GoogleLogout } from 'react-google-login';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FcGoogle } from 'react-icons/fc';
import shareVideo from '../assets/share.mp4';
import logo from '../assets/logowhite.png';

import { client } from '../client';

const Login = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const responseGoogle= (response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profile.Obj));

    const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;

    const doc = {
      _id: googleId,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: imageUrl,
    }

    client.createIfNotExists(doc)
      .then(() => {
        navigate('/', { replace: true })
      })
  }
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen'>
      <div className='relative w-full h-full'>
          <video 
            src={shareVideo}
            type='video/mp4'
            loop
            controls={false}
            muted
            autoPlay
            className='w-full h-full object-cover'
          />
          <div className='absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay'>
              <div className='p-5'>
                  <img src={logo} width='130px' alt='Ack! This WAS a logo :/' />
              </div>

              <div className='shadow-2xl'>
                    <GoogleLogin 
                      clientId="380323139927-1809a59ll0fp29rfo40jmubp01c2ife8.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                      render={(renderProps) => (
                        <button
                          type='button'
                          className='bg-mainColor flex justify-center items-center p-3 rounded-lg cursor-pointer outline-none'
                          onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                          disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                          onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                          onFailure={responseGoogle}
                          cookiepolicy='single-host-origin'
                        >
                          <FcGoogle className='mr-4' /> Sign in with Google
                        </button>
                      )}  
                      
                    />
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Here is my index.js file if needed:

```
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';
import './index.css'

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);


root.render(
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

If anyone knows anyway to sort this out I would appreciate it hugely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be helpful to post the code for client.createIfNotExists as well, since that is what your navigate() is wrapped in and I assume is the line that is causing the issue here.

Comment: How far into the login process is *your* code getting? Have you stepped through the code starting from getting the response back from Google? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Can you also share the `App.js` component with the routings please? Also, do you have a case for when the `client.createIfNotExists(doc)`is false(meaning the doc already exists)? like @pzutils said that could be actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profile.Obj));
```

shouldn't it be:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));
```

there is no "." between profile and Obj

Comment: Formatting is bad